# Как передать значение переменной из фронта в бэкенд?

Tags: javascript, java, html

Например есть html страничка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Lern js</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add" onsubmit="convertArray(listOfNumbersId)">
    <textarea Id='listOfNumbersId' name="listOfNumbersName" col='20' rows='30'></textarea>
    <p><input id='listOfNumbersButton' type='button' value="Submit" onclick='showMe(listOfNumbersId)'></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    var arrayOfLines = [];

    function showMe(message) {
        alert(message.value);
    }

    function convertArray(text) {
        arrayOfLines = text.value.split('\n');
        alert(arrayOfLines);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Есть одна форма, при ее передаче значение элемента listOfNumbersName я смогу получить с помощью метода getParameter("listOfNumbersName") класа HttpServletRequest.
В html формируется массив arrayOfLines, так вот как его передать и затем получить в java коде?

UPD:
новый html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Lern js</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="add" onsubmit="convertArray(listOfNumbersId)" method="post">
    <textarea Id='listOfNumbersId' name="listOfNumbersName" col='20' rows='30'></textarea>
    <p><input id='listOfNumbersButton' type='button' value="Submit" onclick='showMe(listOfNumbersId)'></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
    var arrayOfLines = [];

    function showMe(message) {
        alert(message.value);
    }

    function convertArray(text) {
        arrayOfLines = text.value.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n").split('\n');
        alert(arrayOfLines);
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

сервлет:

```
 @PostMapping("/add")
    public ModelAndView add(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        number_parse.fillParams(new String[]{
                "RIM",
                "100",
                "XYABZWTUPL",
                "A!=B",
                "X",
                "A=1",
                "1",
                "",
                ""
        });

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        String[] array = (String[]) session.getAttribute("arrayOfLines");
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            list.add(number_parse.generateInsert(array[i], 10));
        }

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("otvet");
        mv.addObject("str", "MDAAAA");
        mv.addObject("kek", list);
        return mv;
    }
```

Comment: http post запросом например

Comment: А можно, пожалйуста, пример?

Comment: Вам, как я вижу, уже ответили, Вы разобрались?

Comment: нет, Вы можете помочь?

Comment: у Вас сервер на локальной машине? какой адрес сервлета? `http://localhost:8080/test/add` что то такое?

Comment: Да, верно. C формы localhost:8080 хочу отправить на сервлет, а после на localhost:8080/add

Comment: Вот на такой запрос что происходит? https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send

Comment: Request method 'POST' not supported
Вот как написал в html:
let arrayOfLines = text.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n").split('\n');
        
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("post", "/insert", true);

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Вызывает функцию при смене состояния.
            if(request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) {
            alert("messege");
            }
        }
        request.send();

Comment: html страницу, с которой Вы делаете запрос, сервер нормально отдает, по какому адресу Вы к нему обращаетесь?

Comment: Не особо понял вопрос(

Answer (score 1):

Сделайте в вашей форме `post-запрос`

```
<form action="add" onsubmit="convertArray(listOfNumbersId)" method="post">
```

Это позволит форме отравить данные на сервлет `"add"`

а в java-коде получаете эти данные с помощью `HttpSession` в специальном методе `doPost`

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
HttpSession session = request.getSession();

String [] arrayOfLines = (String[])session.getAttribute("listOfNumbersName");
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, только все равно не выходит, изменил html и приложил сервлет в вопросе, посмотри, пожалуйста, где я не прав.
при выполнеии части:
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            list.add(number_parse.generateInsert(array[i], 10));
        }
из сервлета получаю ошибку:
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: ВладПирогов Моя вина, не туда всунул post С правильными кавычками все должно работать

Comment: Не понял, где и что именно менять?

Comment: @ВладПирогов В сервлете сделайте метод doPost

Comment: @ВладПирогов как в ответе написано и поместите туда код с HttpSession

Comment: я поместил этот код в метод add сервлета, и там он не дает нужного результата, какая разница как метод будет назыаться? может я конечно не вижу очевидных вещей, но мне все равно не ясно.

Comment: @ВладПирогов Формой вы создаете post-запрос, который перенаправляет вас в сервлет add, но  в сервлете вы его не обрабатываете. (doGet и doPost) два стандартных метода, которые выполняются при обработке соответствующих запросов. У вас в коде нет этого обработчика.

Comment: @ВладПирогов и еще может быть проблема в том что функцию вы вызываете с помощью onsubmit. а кнопок submit у вас на форме нет

Comment: кнопка submit есть, но мапинги Get запросов же работают несмотря на то что нет метода doGet

Comment: @ВладПирогов кнопка с текстом submit есть но тип у нее button, а нужен тип submit вроде

Comment: <p><input type="submit" value="Submit">